# How do I model a message interface between two c++ classes (in difference threads) in UML?

Tags: c++, uml, class-diagram

What I have is:

- Two different classes that are in different threads (say classA and classB).
- They do not know anything about each other (no includes / forward decls).
- When classA has finished something it posts a message (the routing is handled elsewhere), and classB receives it.

That's all really. In my class diagram, I want to show that classA and classB have messages passing between them (i.e. can communicate) and that they are in different threads.

Is this possible in UML class diagram? - is there a "communicates" relationship syntax?
If UML does not do this then I will just make up my own method to show this, but if there is a standard I may as well use it!

Answer (score 3):

To depict threads you can use Activity diagrams, Sequence Interaction diagrams and/or State diagram

- Activity diagrams - Allows for forking and specifying
  concurrency/synchronization by using a **BAR** and usage lines.
- Sequence Interaction diagrams - allow you to specify parallel
  behavior within a sequence by boxing parallelizable behavior with a
  label "par"
- State diagram - The state chart just like the activity allows for
  concurrency by using a BAR and usage lines.

The image illustrates consumer/producer pattern in UML activity diagram:

[image]

[Modeling_Java_Threads_in_UML](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/2803977_Modeling_Java_Threads_in_UML/file/79e4150c241f6b12b5.pdf)

Comment: Thank you for that. The document has some nice UML examples to follow and you have a nice explanation (+1), but I really just wanted to know if you can show which thread a class belongs to in the class diagram (even though its not necessarily meant to do this). I don't want to show the level of detail of an activity or state diagram. Anyway, I just made colored areas in the background to show this and it looks nice :)

Answer (score 2):

> Is this possible in UML class diagram? - is there a "communicates" relationship syntax?

Just put notes or a (stereotyped) dependency. It's not possible to express this in an UML class diagram. Class diagrams are inherently not for showing the behavioral aspects, but the structure and static relationships of class types.

Good diagram types to represent concurrent behavior in your system are Activity or State diagrams.

**UPDATE**
Though one reasonable UML standard compliant way to mark classes as *running in separate threads*, is to declare them as 'Active Class':

> An active object is an object that, as a direct consequence of its creation, commences to execute its classifier behavior, and does not cease until either the complete behavior is executed or the object is terminated by some external object. (This is sometimes referred to as "the object having its own thread of control.") The points at which an active object responds to communications from other objects is determined solely by the behavior of the active object and not by the invoking object. If the classifier behavior of an active object completes, the object is terminated.
>
> *UML Superstructure Specification, v2.1.1, p. 438*

It's rendered like this:
[image: 'Active Class' notation visual representation]

Anyway the possible path's of communications between such class elements can be expressed via the mentioned stereotyped dependency relationships.

For Activity / State Diagrams you can think about such asynchronous message interactions in terms of `Signal` and `Event` elements.

Comment: Thanks very much, I did not think there was :(  I know its not a specific feature of class diagrams, but its very useful for the reader to show some basic/fundamental behaviors if its convenient. But as you say I can just put a note between them saying "this talks to that" :)

Comment: Oh yeah, what about "thread spaces" that the classes live in? - I assume also its the same answer :)

Comment: @code_fodder Our UML tool (Enterprise Architect) supports to set an 'Is Active' tag for class elements, and one can select 'Show Runstate'. I've been using this earlier, to show that a class will mainly run with an internally managed thread (it's rendered as two vertical bars at the left and right side of the class)

Comment: Hmm... an interesting feature. Sometimes you are limited in what you can show with certain UML diagrams.

Comment: @code_fodder _Sometimes you are limited ..._ Happily our tool provides to setup UML profiles (including provision of rendering capabilities based on tags and stereotypes) relatively easy :-D. I can just recommend EA, the relation of price and power is pretty good (I've even bought a license for my private use). Here's a link to that [Active Class](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/9.3/standard_uml_models/activeclasses.html) feature I mentioned. It has also a UML Standard cite for V2.2.